# Wanting to prevent someone from taking a snapshot

Tags: android

I'm building a app for a business. In this app I'm wanting to place some exclusive coupons people can use at the store for having the app installed. Because its a free app, I'm going to have ads placed in the app. Wanting to keep the rev coming in, I don't want people to just take a snapshot of the coupons, and then delete the app... Is there a way to prevent them from doing this? Or is there a way I could have a VOID pop up on the snapshot of the coupon when they take the snapshot?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to prevent them from doing this?

Ultimately: no. You can only make it *difficult,* not *impossible,* to take a screenshot; consider how difficult it is for the average user to take a screenshot at all.<sup>1</sup> Once the data is shown on the screen, you've lost the game. Example: take a picture of the screen with a separate camera.

What you *can* do, however, is make each coupon unique, and valid for one use only. That means you'll have to keep track of every coupon issued, but it does prevent abuse.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Very, pre-Android 4: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1759/how-to-take-a-screenshot-with-an-android-phone</sub>

Comment: Thanks... Is there a way we can have a key generator, that will load a different number every time they open the coupon up. Then all we would have to do is keep a database of how many times the customer used the same number?

Comment: That would still allow the user to generate an infinite number of coupons, no? And doesn't that defeat the purpose?

Comment: Don't think it would defeat the purpose. Cuz it would only be exclusive to people using the app. Not to the people not using the app. But thanks!!! You been helpful!

Comment: To answer your question _"Is there a way we can have a key generator, that will load a different number"_ yes, that is absolutely possible. Go write some code `:)`